# mongo aggregation $facet and grouping ask

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

My aggregation is this.

[image]

These are result..

[image]

I wanna get bottom result.

[image]

How to aggregate this result ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cthurston/7aead8229e10caa0be175babf7e8ddf1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) aggregation pipeline stages after [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "data": { "$concatArrays": ["$all", "$part"] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are genius !

Comment: OK. I'm makred. Thank you!
@Anthony Winzlet